# Raise array to the power of another array - i.e. expanding the dimension of the array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, matrix

Is it possible to use numpy to raise an array to the power of another array, in a way that yields a result with a larger dimension than the inputs - i.e. not just simple element wise raising to the power of.

As a simple example, I'm looking to compute the following. Below is the "longhand" form - in practice this is implemented by a loop over a large `x` array, so it's slow.

```
x = np.arange(4)
t = np.random.rand(3,3)

y = np.empty_like(x)
y[0] = np.sum(x[0]**t)
y[1] = np.sum(x[1]**t)
y[2] = np.sum(x[2]**t)
y[3] = np.sum(x[3]**t)
```

I'd like a vectorised solution to replace doing `y[i]` each time. However, since x has shape `[4]` and y has shape `[3,3]`, when I try to compute `x**t` I get an error.

Is there a fast optimized solution?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Sorry for the delay as I was testing it out a little. Works nicely thanks - and very clean code! numexpr actually takes longer in my case bu that's probably computer-dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight-forward vectorized way would be with `broadcasting` -

```
y = (x[:,None,None]**t).sum((1,2)).astype(x.dtype)
```

Or with the builtin `np.power.outer` -

```
y = np.power.outer(x,t).sum((1,2)).astype(x.dtype)
```

---

For large arrays, leverage multi-cores with `numexpr` module -

```
import numexpr as ne

y = ne.evaluate('sum(x3D**t1D,1)',{'x3D':x[:,None],'t1D':t.ravel()}).astype(x.dtype)
```